# Matlab: How to specify input in matlabFunction?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, symbolic-math

`matlabFunction()` is a function that can convert symbolic to anonymous function. But how to specify what input arguments to be appeared on the anonymous function?

For example,

```
x = sym('x', [3, 1])
func = matlabFunction(x)
```

It returns a handle with:

```
func =

  function_handle with value:

    @(x1,x2,x3)[x1;x2;x3]
```

But how to make this to be returned:?

```
@(x) [x(1); x(2); x(3)]
```

that the whole `x` is the input arguments, not every element of it. This could be extremely useful when `x` has very long colums.

Comment: I can tell you how  `x` can be used as an input to the anonymous function `@(x1,x2,x3,..)`. will that be acceptable?

Comment: @SardarUsama what if `x` has 100 elements, it would be a disater to write down them all.

Comment: I can tell you how to do that automatically. I am not suggesting to manually write them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making that anonymous function, you can input the elements of `x` as a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) to `func` by first [converting `x` to a cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html).

```
xcell = num2cell(x);
func(xcell{:})
```