# How can vector elements with indexing be used in a MATLAB symbolic expression?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I would like to create a MATLAB function with vector inputs. The problem is that the inputs of a function created by matlabFunction() has only scalar inputs.

```
x = sym('x',[2 1]);
y = sym('y',[2 1]);
f=x(1)+x(2)+y(1)+y(2);
matlabFunction(f,'file','testFunction.m');
matlabFunction(f,'file','testFunction.m','vars',[x,y]); % tried with different options but doesn't work
```

This is the result (with x1,x2,y1,y2 inputs instead of x,y):

```
function f = testFunction(x1,x2,y1,y2)
%TESTFUNCTION
%    F = TESTFUNCTION(X1,X2,Y1,Y2)

%    This function was generated by the Symbolic Math Toolbox version 8.2.
%    10-Apr-2019 21:28:40

f = x1+x2+y1+y2;
```

Is there a solution to this problem within MATLAB? Or do I need to write a program opening the file as txt and replacing the words...

Update: I managed to solve the problem. For me, the best solution is the odeToVectorField() function.

Manually it is more difficult to give vector inputs to a function created by matlabFunction(). One way is the following:

```
syms y;
f=str2sym('y(1)+y(2)');
matlabFunction(f,'File','fFunction','Vars',y);
```

With this method, you need to manipulate the equation as a string (which is possible but not practical...), then re-convert it to symbolic expression.

Comment: Why do you need vector inputs? If you want to give inputs to that function as vectors, you can use my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54709163/5698672)

Comment: Vector inputs are convenient when x is a long vector.
I'm not sure how this cell array method works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: How to specify input in matlabFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709163/matlab-how-to-specify-input-in-matlabfunction)

Comment: I would like to use the MATLAB function in Simulink. Your solution only works for MATLAB function calls.

In Simulink, I can use a wrapper function which has vector inputs and calls the main function with scalar inputs (the elements of the vectors).

Sorry, I haven't mentioned Simulink. Your solution is simplier because in my wrapper function, I have to manually access the elements of the vector while the num2cell() function does it automatically. But num2cell() isn't supported in Simulink.

Comment: This is the error message: <https://imgur.com/tB7VDN0>
The code of the function:
`function y = fcn(u)
ucell = num2cell(u);
y = u;`  (There are 3 rows, I can't write the code into the comment properly.)

Comment: This is an  [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about X, you've asked about Y. Please [edit] your ***original question*** to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you check the result of `f=x(1)+x(2)+y(1)+y(2)` you will see that it is also scalar. Do simple test:

```
x = sym('x',[2 1]);
y = sym('y',[2 1]);
f=x(1)+x(2)+y(1)+y(2);
disp(f)
```

The results is `x1 + x2 + y1 + y2`. So there's nothing wrong with your `matlabFunction` expression, it just save what you give. If you need it to be stored in the form `x(1)+x(2)+y(1)+y(2)` you need to rewrite your `f` expression so it will be stored in vector form, until passing it to `matlabFunction`. Or alternatively you can create your file structure manualy using `fprintf`, [look docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).

Comment: You are right, it is stored in the `x1 + x2 + y1 + y2` form. The problem is, when I write the `f` expression, MATLAB evaluates `x(1)` into `x1`. I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: It's a different question. I'm not an expert of symbolic math toolbox.